# How to make a waveform simulation in Quartus II from testbench module

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, quartus, testbench

[image]
[image]

I wrote a Verilog gate-level description and a testbench for these requirements. However, I don't know how to make a waveform simulation in Quartus II. How can I make the waveform simulation to get the result like this:

[image]

My code is here:

```
// Verilog model of simple circuit with propagation delay
`timescale 1ns/100ps
module practicechapter3 (F, x, y);
    output F;
    input x, y;
    wire w1, w2, w3, w4;
    not #3 (w1, y);
    not #3 (w2, x);
    and #6 (w3, x, w1);
    and #6 (w4, y, w2);
    or  #8 (F, w3, w4);
endmodule 

// Test bench for this circuit
module t_practicechapter3();
    wire F;
    reg x, y;
    practicechapter3 M0(F, x, y);
    initial
    begin 
    x = 1'b0; y = 1'b0;
    #100 y = 1'b0;
    end
    initial #200 $finish;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close.

In the testbench module (`t_practicechapter3`), change the `initial` block as follows:

```
initial
begin 
   x = 0;
   y = 0;
   #10 y = 1;
end
```

The delay values should be changed from `#100` to `#10` because the timescale you used is 1ns.

Also, after 10 time units, you want `y` to go from 0 to 1.

I omitted the base prefix (`1'b`) in all the assignments to make it more obvious which values are 0 vs. 1.  Sometimes it is confusing to see `1'b0` and know that it represents 0 and not 1.

Comment: Yes, I will correct it. But I still don't know how to make a waveform in Quartus II.
I mean I don't know what buttons I need to click to generate the waveform.

Comment: @Southgoodman: I don't use Quartus, but I just googled "quartus ii waveform", and a bunch of video tutorials showed up.  I'd start there.

Comment: I usually follow this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8JAkKhxlQI) to make a waveform simulation in Quartus II. But it's still very handmade, I have to designate x with T = 1us, y with T = 2us, set end Time, and grid size.
When it comes to auto-generating input waves by testbench file, I haven't found any tutỏials yet.

Comment: @Southgoodman: You should do input stimulus by hand in the Verilog code.